# Filed 83(b) election in wrong IRS center. Should I file again?

Tags: united-states, irs, 83b-election

I filed my 83(b) on time at the incorrect IRS center (Austin). Assuming I have enough time, should I re-file it at the correct location (Fresno) or is it OK?

Comment: Should be OK. All the data winds up in the same place; the government just wants to distribute the workload of accepting it.